# I can not show images from Storage folder laravel 5 using Digital Ocean

Tags: php, laravel-5, storage, web-deployment, digital-ocean

I deployed Laravel 5.2 proyect 2 days ago on Digital Ocean. Using Lamp with ubuntu.

I use `$pic = "../storage/pic/pic_1.jpg"` in the Controller for local project and i the view

```
<img src="{!!$pic !!}">
```

Now i deployed in a remote server and only `/public` pictures are displaying.

I want to work with Storage folder , for security.

I tried

`$pic = "/var/www/myproject/storage/pic/pic_1.jpg"`

`$pic = storage_path()."/pic/pic_1.jpg"`

`$pic = storage_path(pic/pic_1.jpg)`

`$pic = storage_path('pic/pic_1.jpg')`

and didn't work

The only one that works is this, because the image is on `/public` dir
`<img src="http://xx.xx.xx.xx/images/agu_web5.jpg">`

But, I can access to documents in Storage, So I had permission on `/var/www/myproject/storage`

```
$path_doc = "../storage/doc/".$doc->path;
return response()->download($path_doc);
```

Can i use dir  storage on a deployed server with pictures?

Comment: `$pic = storage_path('pic/pic_1.jpg');`

Comment: Thanks @ShobiPP but doesn't work

Comment: Does `storage` has enough priviledges?